# NodeJS Base-64 encoding of the SHA-512 digest

Tags: node.js, cryptojs

I am using the Starling Bank web hooks to call my API.  They state the following:

> The signature is placed in the header of the request using
>   X-Hook-Signature and consists of Base-64 encoding of the SHA-512
>   digest of the secret + JSON payload.

My code that I ended up with is below. Having tried different ways, I can not seem to get the same Base-64 of the SHA-512 as what is in the header. Am I understanding/using the crypto and bodyParser library correctly?

```
// middleware.js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
import * as crypto from 'crypto';

export const auth = (req, res, next) => {
    let hash = crypto.createHash('sha512');
    hash.update(config.starling.key + req.rawBody));
    req.hasha = hash.digest('base64');

    // req.hasha is different from req.header('X-Hook-Signature')

    next();
}
```

My app has the following code

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as cors from 'cors';
import * as middleware from './middleware';
import bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(middleware.auth);

// Endpoints removed for brevity

export const hooks = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Is `req.rawBody` always the same content?

Comment: No, the body contains JSON for the newly inserted data that triggered the webhook to fire.

Comment: Then, what do you mean by "I can not seem to get the same Base-64 of the SHA-512 as what is in the header"? If `req.rawBody` is different, it makes sense that you never get identical Base64 result.

Comment: If I understood correctly you are trying to re-encode the data that you already know just to verify them with the signature. How about decrypting the `X-Hook-Signature` and check what's inside? That way you will know what you are missing.

Comment: Also, what kind of security measure is this? They give you the data in `req.body` and a hashed version of them in the `X-Hook-Signature`? This would make sense if you were to send them data so they can verify the body with the signature (which contains your secret).

Comment: They send the Base-64 encoding of the SHA-512 digest of the secret + JSON payload in the header.  I then take the body received, append it to the secret and calculate the Base-64 of the Sha-512 of that.  That was I know that the data I received is in fact from them (unless my secret was compromised).

Comment: Yes, my mistake... It's not just `Base64` but it's encrypted with `SHA-512`, so my point to just decrypt is not valid.

Comment: @Pieter did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @smashah No I didn't.  I moved on to more important but I will definitely give your answer a try, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that express and bodyParser are messing with the rawBody.

This should work:

```js
const express = require("express");
const crypto = require('crypto');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json({
  verify: (req, res, buf) => {
    req.rawBody = buf
  }
}));

app.post('/starling',async (request,response)=>{

  const secret = 'abcd-efgh-12f3-asd34-casd-whatever';

  let hash = crypto.createHash('sha512');

  hash.update(secret+request.rawBody);

  const sigCheck = hash.digest('base64');
  
  const valid = sigCheck==request.headers['x-hook-signature'];
});
```

Comment: Just got around to testing it and it works perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: @Pieter I made a simple express middleware to automatically verify requests: https://www.npmjs.com/package/starling-verifier

Comment: That will definitely make things easier!  Thanks

Comment: Starling has now added examples for different languages to their GitHub which might help someone in the future: https://github.com/starlingbank/api-samples/tree/master/webhook-verification